# Is it possible to add/remove arp-ip-targets without taking the bonding interface up/down

Tags: linux, networking, bonding

I just changed in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0`:

`BONDING_OPTS="mode=active-backup arp_interval=1000 arp_ip_target=10.0.0.1"`

and now I want to set those arp_interval and arp_ip_target temporarily so I don't have to restart the interface.

I know to set the arp_interval: `echo 1000 > /sys/class/net/bond0/bonding/arp_interval`
but the same isn't working in: `/sys/class/net/bond2/bonding/arp_ip_target`

so is there a different way?

System is: RHEL 6.3

I found these 2 Documentations:

- [Linuxfoundation Documentation](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/bonding)
- [RedHat Documentation](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Using_Channel_Bonding.html)

But as far as I can see:

- The least I have to do is get the interface up/down, which isn't
  working on my test-server.
- Or a network restart, which only works for adding, but not removing arp_ip_targets.

I'll keep looking, because reboot/network restart is unacceptable. I could live with restarting/initializing only one bonding interface at the same time, but I can't get it to work like that yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to my question was easier than i thought, arp_ip_targets can be added and removed like this:

```
echo +10.0.0.1 > /sys/class/net/bond0/bonding/arp_ip_target
echo -10.0.0.1 > /sys/class/net/bond0/bonding/arp_ip_target
```

that doesn't even need a restart of the interface!